# Windows 10 is running slow / upgrade ideas

Tags: performance, windows-10, upgrade

I need your advice. I have installed Windows 10 about 2 months ago, I see it is running
slower **every day**, it takes ages to shut down or start some program.
User Interface becomes not responsive sometimes

I have installed several
"heavy" applications, MS Visual Studio 17, 19, Office 16, DataGrip, Adobe Reader.

My Task Manager displays 100% CPU usage most of time and 80% of memory. It seems that it consumes
all available CPU and memory regardless of how many applications are running

Can you suggest how can I improve performance of my Windows?
I am looking at:

1. Removing some services
2. Putting Windows to SDD drive (currently I have 200 Gb HDD drive)
3. Increasing DIMM memory ( currently I have 7 GB)
4. Upgrade CPU (Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 6 Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E8400@3.00GHz)

Please share your ideas

[image]

Comment: "Increasing DIMM memory ( currently I have 7 GB)" - you know what has 8gb? my 5 year old tablet.

Comment: @TomTom you made me laugh, it's a nice one haha

Comment: What's the memory type (DDR2, 3, 4)?

Comment: Iti s not only a good one - 8gb is recommended minimum for Visual Studio and that leaves no room for actually debugging anything more complex than a calculator. I sometimes top 40gb in active use with Visual Studio in debugging, with a dozen background images starting to build an environment. 7gb is ignoring the reality, as it anyway the amazingly crappy old CPU, which is 12 years old and 45nm.

Comment: Your computer is more than a decade old. It is not going to handle many modern tasks well, certainly not anything involving development. Don't waste your money on upgrades; no upgrades you can do to this system will help enough to give acceptable performance for the programs you want to run. It's time for a new computer.

Comment: Memory type is DDR2, motherboard is P5K-VM, anyway I see now this PC is really old crap

Answer (score 1):

You should consider upgrading your CPU first. A Core 2 Duo is reaaaally old, and you can get a decent i5 (or even i7) nowadays without any problem. The main objective is to have more than 2 poor cores.

Regarding the RAM, it could be helpful to upgrade it to (at least) 16Go. You can find some cheap RAM (don't go for the high frequencies, only purist can see the real difference imho).

The disk is also an important upgrade part. As you said, having an SSD for the system would be really helpful. Using a SSD removes the problem of the slow magnetic head going through the whole disk.

Btw notice that we won't do any piece suggestion here, and your question should have been asked to Super User instead of Server Fault.